# Get Keyboard state in Universal Windows Apps

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I want to detect a key combination (e.g. `Control-A`) in a Windows App. The `KeyDown` event handler has information about the last key pressed. But how do I find out whether the Control key is pressed as well?

Comment: Normally you do `KeyPressed == Control | A`

Comment: @KevinKal Thanks. But I tried that. It was only `A`.

Comment: Control is a system key so it is logged differently. I'm not sure how it's done but that's the issue you're seeing

Comment: @rmn36 Yes. And in WPF we can use the `Keyboard` class for that. Unfortunately, in UWP that isn't accessible.

Comment: Windows Hooks? I'm sorry I've never worked in UWP

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `CoreVirtualKeyStates.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)` to determine is the *Ctrl* key has been pressed, like this -

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
    if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) && e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.A)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, instead of subscribing to the `KeyDown` event of your page, subscribe to `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` as in my answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do we capture the function Keys. I tried using CoreWindow.KeyDown, CoreWindow.CharacterReceived and none of these working. Do i have to set anything on CoreWindow level to capture Function keys?

Answer (score 8):

You can use AcceleratorKeyActivated event, irrespective of where the focus is it will always capture the event.

```
public MyPage()
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += AcceleratorKeyActivated;
}


private void AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.EventType.ToString().Contains("Down"))
    {
        var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
        if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down))
        {
            switch (args.VirtualKey)
            {
                case VirtualKey.A:
                    Debug.WriteLine(args.VirtualKey);
                    Play_click(sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```