# UWP Ctrl+F implementation

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, find, shortcut

I'm creating an UWP app (C# .NET) where there is textbox. I want to implement a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to search texts in the textbox. I know how to find texts, but I don't know how to implement the shortcut.

I found this:

```
if ((e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F) || (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)) 
{
    //do something
}
```

...but it isn't working for UWP. I tried this (textarea is name of textbox):

```
private void textarea_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control) && (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.F))
    {
        flayoutFind.ShowAt(appBarButtonFind as FrameworkElement);
    }
}
```

but it isn't working too. How can I do it?

And for the future, is there any way, how to override default functionality and shortcut of textbox <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (undo)?

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32782168/6741868) you could try using `Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control)` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using "Accelerators" and "Access keys" as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/keyboard-interactions

Basically, you will have to register for events

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;

private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
    {
         //Implementation
    }
```

You can check the sample in detail here: https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/SQLServer/BuildDemo/MainPage.xaml.cs